# Yet another Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker-errors

I built an app 2 months ago and now I want to work with it again. I opened up the project today and I am getting the error as follows:

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Why do I get this error?

[build fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyw97.png)

[pod folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylc20.png)

Comment: Try legacy build

Comment: no success with legacy

Comment: Try deleting the derived data and doing pod install

Comment: Open the Build tab and show the details of the linker failure.  This is not enough information.

Comment: Can you click on that error and show the build process? It will normally say which file is causing the issue

Comment: updated with the screenshot from the build process. Deleting derived data and pod install no success

Comment: Can you show your podfile? And the target version of your main project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker error is because you can't find pods. Try the following:

- Close Xcode
- `pod install`
- Open workspace

If that doesn't work:

- Close Xcode
  `pod update`
- Open workspace

If that still doesn't work:

- Close Xcode
- Delete derived data
- Delete Pods folder and Podfile.lock
- `pod update`
- Open workspace

If that **STILL** doesn't work... it could be your project's deployment target, make sure the targetted version is the same in both your project and the podfile.

Comment: Tried everything with no success. How can I check the targeted versions?

Comment: Click on your main target on your project and then the general tab, it's in there. Then you can take a look in your Podfile

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I edited a picture from my pod folder which I found. I think there is a problem

Comment: I deleted all files in the pod folder (in navigator) and installed all pods again. Now it works but the files in the framework folder are still red

Comment: If they're red then they're references that are just hanging around. You can delete those and re-run `pod install`. If that's worked, can you mark this as the correct answer? :)

Comment: doesnt work. Still red.. The app works again but this looks not like it should haha. Or can I ignore the red framework files?

Comment: It should be fine, it could be an issue with your podfile targets but it shouldn't stop you running the app

Answer (score 0):

As the picture say, can't find the pods. Just simply reinstall them with `pod update`. And ofcourse, don't forget to use .xworkspace files.